# Open qcow2 image on debian remote server remotely

Tags: debian, kvm, qemu, qcow2

I recovered a vmware image from an inaccessible server after converting it to qcow2, now it is on a remote debian server (kimsufi) and as it is 64GB I can't download it to my small pc.

I read that I need KVM to open it but it doesn't seems possible to install it on my server. Is there alternatives? How to do it?

My goal is to recover some important files.

Comment: Are you trying to run this image or just recover data?

Comment: Look into `qemu-nbd`; `qemu` also supports (read-only) http/s images via the curl library (but which you can probably combine with the `-snapshot` option). That's all described in the manpage.

Comment: @GAD3R I tried some tutorials but them all refer to `/etc/network/interfaces` that doesn't exists on my server.

Comment: @ajgringo619 my goal is to recover some important files.

Comment: @mosvy thank you I recovered my files ! Add this as a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can recover data from a qcow2 image, provided that it is not encrypted. Download the image to your local pc. Then use 7zip to open the file. You can the drag and drop important files that you need to recover.
 [image]